# my server can't connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have server x that for gameserver.
and I have mysql5.5.
when I connect server to db i got this message

> **Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client**

my.ini is set old_passwords=1

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES like 'old_passwords';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| old_passwords | 1     |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set
```

and when i try to use mysql 4.0.27-nt-max it can be connect successfully.
but i can't use php to connect db mysql 4.0.27-nt-max

Comment: you shouldn't be running mysql 4.x anymore. that's an ancient branch. upgrade to at least a 5.x version.

Comment: very nice, now update your mysql..

Comment: yeah, but when i upgrade to mysql 5.5 i got "Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client"

Comment: And why don't you upgrade the client? (ie the PHP libs)

Comment: I updated.
when i run the server ,server trying to connected DB but i got "Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client" What that mean?

ps: full error message from server "[DB]Error mysql_real_connect(GAMEDBSERVER): Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client"

Comment: "*consider upgrading MySQL client*" refers to the PHP binary and the MySQL library bundled with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have a copy of MySQL 4.0 around, I would guess you also have an ancient version of PHP.

https://support.zend.com/hc/en-us/articles/203838366-mysql-connect-Client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol

> Many older PHP builds use the MySQL client API for MySQL 3.23.x. If you use an older PHP build (with the old MySQL API) then you will get the Client does not support authentication protocol error when trying to connect to a MySQL server 4.1.x or above.
>
> The recommended solution is to upgrade your PHP to the latest ...

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this problem, the preferred solution is to upgrade all client programs to use a 4.1.1 or higher client library. If that is not possible, use one of the following approaches:

To connect to the server with a pre-4.1 client program, use an account that still has a pre-4.1-style password.

Reset the password to pre-4.1 style for each user that needs to use a pre-4.1 client program. This can be done using the SET PASSWORD statement and the OLD_PASSWORD() function:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR
    -> 'some_user'@'some_host' = OLD_PASSWORD('new_password');
```

Substitute the password you want to use for “new_password” in the preceding example. MySQL cannot tell you what the original password was, so you'll need to pick a new one.

Tell the server to use the older password hashing algorithm by default:

Start mysqld with the old_passwords system variable set to 1.

Assign an old-format password to each account that has had its password updated to the longer 4.1 format. You can identify these accounts with the following query:

```
mysql> SELECT Host, User, Password FROM mysql.user
    -> WHERE LENGTH(Password) > 16;
```

For each account record displayed by the query, use the Host and User values and assign a password using one of the methods described previously.